# C++ executable signing in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, redhat, sign

I have a set of executable and shared object files in Linux built using GCC. I am looking for a way to digitally sign these. What could be the best way in Linux equivalent to Sign Tool for Windows?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/390213/does-linux-have-a-signature-system-for-executables, https://lwn.net/Articles/733431/

Comment: basically packages are signed, executables and libraries aren't

Answer (score 0):

If you create AppImage executables, you can sign them. See https://docs.appimage.org/packaging-guide/optional/signatures.html

Comment: Link is broken (as of 2021-03-19). They say, however, that "As this documentation is still work in progress, the content might have been moved".

Comment: @LaryxDecidua Thanks! I updated the URL.